# Images not showing in update function using BackPack for Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I´m saving images in my crud. The url is being stored in the DB correctly, however the image is not appearing when I try to edit the element. The image shows like this:

[image]

I'm using this mutator:

```
public function setImageAttribute($value)
{
    $evidencia = "image";
    $disk = "public";
    $destination_path = "public/uploads/evidenciaQuejas";

    // if the image was erased
    if ($value==null) {
        // delete the image from disk
        \Storage::disk($disk)->delete($this->{$evidencia});

        // set null in the database column
        $this->attributes[$evidencia] = null;
    }

    // if a base64 was sent, store it in the db
    if (starts_with($value, 'data:image'))
    {
        // 0. Make the image
        $image = \Image::make($value)->encode('jpg', 90);
        // 1. Generate a filename.
        $filename = md5($value.time()).'.jpg';
        // 2. Store the image on disk.
        \Storage::disk($disk)->put($destination_path.'/'.$filename, $image->stream());
        // 3. Save the path to the database
        $this->attributes[$evidencia] = $destination_path.'/'.$filename;
    }
}
```

Also, the folder that I created in the server to store the images ("public/uploads/evidenciaQuejas") says it has 0 archives inside even though the image is being stored without errors.

Could you help me please?

Comment: Have you checked your image isn't being saved somewhere else such as storage/app/public?

Comment: I just checked out and it's being saved in /storage/uploads/evidenciaQuejas

Comment: Looks like a file path misconfiguration to me. You're using the `public` disk which I assume is pointing to the `public` directory... then in the `destination_path` you're also beginning with the public directory. Take a closer look at your disk and path, try a different disk or a different path - I'm pretty sure that's your problem.